# How do I use launchctl to hook a shell script to a login / logout event?

Tags: terminal, script

I have been trying to get a shell script to fire on login / logout events on a Mac, but the method I used is very old, and it does not work. I followed [this StackExchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/295924/how-to-run-a-script-at-login-logout-in-os-x) and used the

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook <login script filepath>
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook <logout script filepath>
```

command it describes. However, I learned that this hook is deprecated.

There is some good information in that post about "launchd", and I learned that "launchctrl" might be the modern way of doing what I want to do. However, most of the StackExchange posts I'm finding on this subject are quite outdated.

Could someone please explain in very simple terms which command I need to be using to attach these shell scripts to the login / logout events on a modern Mac using OS X 12+?

For some context, I've already confirmed that the shell scripts themselves work perfectly when launched manually. I now just need them to launch on login and logout.
It is my responsibility to develop the documentation for this process, and I've already developed it successfully for PC, but I have no access to a Mac and haven't used one since the late 90s so I'm working remotely with a colleague who owns a Mac (but doesn't know the terminal / commands) to get this document fleshed out.

Comment: The launchd related answers on the linked post look ok, did you try them?

Comment: Launchd is deprecated, as I understand. The new hook is 'launchctl'

Comment: Launchctl is used to control launchd, it's the same thing at the end.